# Replace objetive function in Word2Vec Gensim

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm doing my final degree project. I need to create an extended version of the word2vec algorithm, changing the default objective function of the original paper. This has already been done (check this [paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fict.2018.00014/full)). In that paper, they only say the new objective function, but they do not say how they have run the model.

Now, I need to extend that model too, with another function, but I'm not sure if I have to implement word2vec myself with the new function, or there is a way to replace it in the Gensim word2vec implementation.

I have checked the [Word2Vec Gensim documentation](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) but I have not seen any parameter to do this. Do you have any idea how to do it? It is even possible?

I was unsure if this StackExchange site was the correct one, maybe https://ai.stackexchange.com/ is more appropriate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no official support in Gensim for simply dropping in your own objective function.

However, the full source code is available – https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim – so by editing it, or using it as a model for your own implementation, you could theoretically do anything.

Beware, though:

- the code has gone through a lot of optimization & customization for new options that may not be relevant to your needs, so may not be the most clean & simple starting point
- for performance, the core routines are written in Cython – see the `.pyx` files – which can be especially hard to debug, and rely on library bulk array functions that may obscure how to implement your alternate function instead